# Proof by induction: $2 ^ {n - 1} \geq n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am trying to make a proof by induction but something is quite not adding up. The inequality to prove is like so.

Prove that:
$$ 2 ^ { n-1} \geq n $$ for $n \geq 0$

My inductive step is like below:

Suppose it works for $n=k$ what about $n = k + 1$
$$ 2^{k-1} \geq k$$
$$ 2^{k-1} + 1 \geq k + 1$$
So we just need to prove that $2^{k-1} \geq 1$ for $k\geq0$

The problem is that when $k=0$, the equation does not hold, i.e. $2^{-1} \geq 1$ is false.
But the inequality to prove works for $k=0$ i.e. $2^{-1}\geq 0$ is true. How can I reconcile this?

Comment: If $n=0$ the inequality would read $2^{-1}≥0$ which is true.

Comment: @lulu yes but in the inductive step it says a false statement

Comment: What statement are you saying is false?  We see no false statements, including those statements which have $k=0$

Comment: @JMoravitz the statement that $2^{0-1} \geq 1$ is false

Comment: Ah... well, if you find yourself in a situation where the induction step with how you have phrased it doesn't quite work for one of the first few cases, you can just have an additional base case to circumvent that.  So, prove base cases $n=0$ and $n=1$, and then show that for $k\geq 1$ that if it works for $k$ that it also works for $k+1$.  Now you do have $2^{k-1}\geq 1$ is true for all $k$ for which you are actually applying the induction step, seen obviously by the fact that $2^k$ is a positive natural number for all natural $k$ and thus greater than or equal to $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz ah. cool. thanks

Comment: Excuse me @Ssenyonjo but shouldn't $n=k+1$ written as $2^{k+1-1} \ge k+1$, which further simplifies to $k \le 0$?

Comment: @AyaanMaan I was adding +1 to both sides. Yes $n=k+1$ is written like that but $k \geq 0$ and not less than as you state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inductive step works for $k\ge1$, so your base case *must hold* for $n=1$ (or more), which it does ($2^{1-1}\ge1$). Taking $n=0$ for the base case will not work.

Hence your inductive proof works only for $n\ge1$. But adding a complementary proof for $n=0$ (i.e. $2^{0-1}\ge 0$) is really nothing.